# android 5.0 notification not showing my define emoji image

Tags: android

`Android 5.0` notification does not show my defined emoji image, it replaces my emoji image by system emoji image. How to resolve?

```
Notification notification = new Notification();
notification.icon = R.drawable.nav_logo;
notification.tickerText = charSequence;//ticker;
notification.when = System.currentTimeMillis();

int defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
notification.defaults = defaults;

notification.contentView = getMessageRemoteView(context, emjin);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    notification.bigContentView = getMessageRemoteView(context, emjin);
}


private static RemoteViews getMessageRemoteView (Context context, String emojin) {
    RemoteViews view = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_msg_item);
    view.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_msg_content,EmojiconUtils.emojify(context, emojin);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: what is `EmojiconUtils` here?

Comment: It's just a tool class replaces emoji unicode with ImageSpan

Comment: Please give us an example of `EmojiconUtils.emojify(context, emojin)` output

Comment: I give the EmojiconUtils class code, you can see.

Answer (score 0):

The EmojiconUtils is a tmp class

```
public class EmojiconUtils {
    public static final String TAG = "EmojiconUtils";

    public static SpannableString emojify(Context context, CharSequence input) {
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(input)) {
            return new SpannableString("");
        }

        SpannableString spanStr = new SpannableString(input);
        while (i < input.length()) {    
            spanStr.setSpan(new ImageSpan(context, getBitmap(context, R.drawable.emoji_1f38d)), i, i + 1, 33);
        }
        return spanStr;
    }

    public static Bitmap getBitmap(Context context, resourceId) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceId);
    }
```

}